# How can a disabled SonarLint rule be re-enabled in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

I disabled a SonarLint rule in IntelliJ, and then decided that it was a mistake. I disabled the rule using the popup in the editor:

[image]

What is the easiest and safest way to re-enable the rule?

The file `sonarlint.xml` in `~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/<product><version>/options/` (on Mac, similar for other platforms) holds the information about the disabled rules. I can probably edit it manually, but it would feel safer with a GUI tool to do it.

Is there a better way to re-enable the rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it. The setting is in Preferences -> Tools -> SonarLint, and NOT in the sub-section Tools -> SonarLint -> Project Settings, where I had looked previously.

Easiest in my case, was to filter the settings by "Show Only Changed":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Now this can be reached in

```
Settings -> Tools -> SonarLint -> Rules -> Restore Default
```

[image]